# Python help to print an object to a string

Tags: python

so I have a project that is pretty straight forward. It's a simple BMI calculator and should just simply print,

"The BMI for (name) is (BMI), (status, like if they're underweight, overweight etc.)

```
name = str(input("What is your name? "))
age = int(input("What is your age? "))
weight_float = float(input("What is your weight in pounds? "))
height_float = float(input("What is your height in inches? "))

Pounds2Kilogram = weight_float * 0.453592
Inches2Meter = height_float * 0.0254

weight = Pounds2Kilogram
height = Inches2Meter


class calcBMI:

    def __init__(self, name, age, weight, height):
        self.__name = name
        self.__age = age
        self.__weight = weight
        self.__height = height

    def getBMI(self):
        return self.__weight / (self.__height **2)

    def getStatus(self):
        if BMI < 18.5:
            self.__getStatus = "Underweight"
        elif 18.5 < BMI < 24.9:
            self.__getStatus = "Normal"
        elif 25.0 < BMI < 29.9:
            self.__getStatus = "Overweight"
        elif BMI > 30:
            self.__getStatus = "Obese"

    def getName(self):
        return self.__name

    def getAge(self):
        return self.__age

    def getWeight(self):
        return self.__weight

    def getHeight(self):
        return self.__height

    def __str__(self):
        return "The BMI for", + self.__name(), + "is", + self.__getBMI()

    def PrintBMI(self):
        print(self.__str__())

a = caclBMI     
print(a)
```

I keep getting:

```
 <class '__main__.calcBMI'>
```

I know that means I need to convert the object to a string and I'm sure I'm missing something simple.

Thanks for helping if you do so choose to.

Comment: what are you getting when you try to print?

Comment: The call to `__getBMI()` in `__str__()` probably doesn't work since it's not defined.

Comment: It looks like you're not actually instantiating the object. You need to instantiate an instance of `CalcBMI`

Comment: Also note that `__str__` method as defined above returns a 4-tuple (if anything) instead of a string.

Comment: `__str__` has problem in syntax, OP used both comma and plus sign which doesn't make sense!

Comment: @WasiAhmad technically, if `__name()` returned (say) integer, there would be no syntax error

Comment: Yes but i complained on the usage of both comma and plus sign!

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> a = caclBMI
> ```

You've rebound `a` to the class. You need to instantiate the class instead.

Answer (score 0):

Just implement `__str__` and `__repr__` methods.

[https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.**str**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__)

[https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.**repr**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__)

```
class calcBMI:
    def __str__(self):
        return "The BMI for {} is {}".format(self.__name, self.getBMI())

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'calcBMI({}, {}, {), {})'.format(self.__name, self.__age, self.__height, self.__weight)

...

a = calcBMI("Zogzog", 123, 210, 176)
print(a)
```

Comment: It looks like OP has implemented `__str__()`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not actually instantiating the object. You need to instantiate an instance of `CalcBMI`

```
...

my_calc_bmi = CalcBMI(my_name, my_age, ...)
print "String representation is: ", my_calc_bmi
print "Or converting explicitly: %s" % (str(my_calc_bmi))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have problem in the following method:

```
def __str__(self):
        return "The BMI for " + self.__name + " is " + str(self.getBMI())
```

Since `self.getBMI()` is returning `float` value, you need to convert it to `string`.

Moreover, you need to instantiate the class instead as follows:

```
a = caclBMI(name, age, weight, height)
```

For example:

```
a = calcBMI('Alex', 25, 100, 60)
print(a)
```

It outputs:

```
The BMI for Alex is 0.027777777777777776
```

Comment: now I'm getting TypeError: 'str' object is not callable,

Comment: I have a = calcBMI(name, age, weight, height)

Comment: make sure you are using - `self.__name` and `str(self.getBMI())`. if not, please update your code and we will be able to check.

Comment: `return "The BMI for",  self.__name,  "is",  str(self.__getBMI())`

Comment: I get the error, **AttributeError: 'calcBMI' object has no attribute '_calcBMI__getBMI'**

Comment: @TheIllusion the method you have written is `getBMI()` not `__getBMI()`. try to understand the error messages, it will help to save your time by quickly understanding the problems of your own.